# Where to put business logic when using entity with MVP pattern

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, mvp

I have entities that are very dumb and only holds the data. I used to put some business logic inside the entities or presenter, i.e.

- `Movie.findMostWatchedTopTenMovies`
- `Movie.hasWatchedThisMovie`
- `TheatrePresenter.canScreenMoreMovies`

(assume that these method contains some complex logic and it's not just getter)

but this seems against the SOLID principle and it's not test friendly code. 
So where is the most appropriate place to put this logic? And what should the class name be?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, It is against SOLID principle and your Models must be atomic, which means they only hold values and do not do any changes by themselves.

By referencing to [Clean Code book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), You must declare some classes that do the changes you want with relevant names, for instance:

```
class MovieFinder{
    public static List<Movie> findMostWatchedTopTenMovies(List<Movie> moviesList){

    // do the fining stuff

    return mostWatchedTopTenMoviesList;
    }
}
```

and even the best thing to do is to crate a new list of items and return it as a result.

Also, for having a pure atomic model you can use [google AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) library which stops you from doing unusual things with models. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should do your data manipulation/logic in BL projects and classes that correlate to entities.

I presume that you are working with some sort of data source like a DB, so you would need the same isolation with data access.
Generally, you would want your BL to contain solely logic (data validation, for example) and your data access to happen inside a DAL (Data Access Layer), which doesn't have logic.

For example, if you have a `Movie` entity:

```
namespace BO
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        ...
    }
}

namespace BL
{
    public class MovieBL
    {
        public Movie GetMovieByName(string name)
        {
            return MovieDAL.GetMovieByName(name);
        }
    }
}
```